# Как активировать curl в PHP на Windows?

Tags: php, php-curl

Раскомментировал строки extension=curl иextension_dir="ext"в php.ini. Но это не помогло. Поэтому, например, функция curl_init() не определена. Как активировать curl в php на Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Ну если мне память не изменяет curl стандартная библиотека php. Для начало выведи функцию `phpinfo()` на экран и посмотри есть ли он у тебя вообще этот Curl.
Картинка, как должно быть.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]